# Extjs3 Component hierarchy - fetch all child components

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm facing the following situation.

> I have a formpanel, within this
>   formpanel I have another tabpanel in
>   which again form elements are placed
>   that are part of the formpanel.
>   Nothing spectacular. Basically a
>   formpanel with some "subforms" each
>   contained in a tab in a tabpanel.

Now I have added code to dis/enable each subform/tab when a user clicks a button in the toolbar. But in order for validation to skip all the formelements in a disabled tab I need to also disable each form field in the tabpanel individually so it skips validation upon submit.

That's when the trouble begins. Suppose in one of the tabs/subforms i have a fieldset with another nested fieldset. 
How can i fetch all xtype:field elements contained in the tab/subform?

---

So basically what i'm asking is **how can i fetch all components that are child components of the tab**, whatever their depth in the component hierarchy is? When i have a method to collect all child components it's easy to just loop over them and disabled the ones that return true from Ext.isXType('field') ... but i have no idea how to gather all subcomponents when i have a reference to it's containing component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
var componentsArray = container.findByType('component');
```

Or even this

```
var componentsArray = container.findBy(function(c) {return true});
```

(should be even faster)

It should be noted however, than this will not return components within `tbar`, `bbar`, `buttons` properties of `Ext.Panel` descendands.

Comment: The documentation is misleading on this. It says "Find **a** component..." but the return type is an Array. Did you verify one way or the other?

Comment: It does in fact return an array of components. See the code, it returns the result of `Ext.Container.findBy()`  In fact, `var componentsArray = container.findBy(function(c) {return true});` should also work :D

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Use `findByType` from Mchl's answer. I got mislead by an error in the Ext documentation.

---

You can use `Ext.Container.prototype.cascade`

> cascade( Function fn, [Object scope], [Array args] ) : Ext.Container
>
> Cascades down the component/container
>   heirarchy from this component (called
>   first), calling the specified function
>   with each component. The scope (this)
>   of function call will be the scope
>   provided or the current component. The
>   arguments to the function will be the
>   args provided or the current
>   component. If the function returns
>   false at any point, the cascade is
>   stopped on that branch.

I used it this way while testing this answer:

```
var children = [];
this.cascade(function(cmp) {
  if (cmp.isXType('field')) {
    children.push(cmp)
  }
});
```

`children` contained 446 instances of field at all different levels.